# Cakephp switch database connection for the entire project

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I switch the database for the entire project like this example:

User 1 uses database test1

User 2 uses database test2

User 3 uses database test3

Like this above... Those ID from User, will come from the default database ( Login page )

PS: Sorry for my bad english, I need some more information, please tell me.

Comment: Why do they need their own database? Sounds like you need to restructure your data.

Comment: Because they are different clients...

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple database configurations in database.php

Let say we have default, test1, test2, test3 configurations.

As you said user data is in default db config and I consider that you are using AUTH COMPONENT for authorization.

Now add following function in AppController

```
    public function beforeFilter() {
        //call change db config function on user login and pass which config need to use
        if( $this->Auth->loggedIn() ) {
            //user login
            ///Some logic to select db config according login user.
            $dbConfig = "result of logic which return db config name";
            $this->_userSpecificDbConfig($dbConfig);
            }
    }

    private function _userSpecificDbConfig($dbConfig) {
        //get model name
        $model =  $this->name;
        //set db configuration for user
        switch($dbConfig) {
            case 'test1':
                $this->{$model}->useDbConfig = "test1";
                break;
            case 'test2':
                $this->{$model}->useDbConfig = "test2";
                break;
            case 'test3':
                $this->{$model}->useDbConfig = "test3";
                break;
            default: 
                $this->{$model}->useDbConfig = "default";
        }
    }
```

Try this code.

Comment: Today I try this ! But this way will change the database for the entire project ? I'm asking, because the $model in your code...for authorization, I'm reading the Session, like this :

           `if (!$this->Session->check('Questionarios.nm_usu')) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('VocÃª nÃ£o estÃ¡ logado.');
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'usuarios', 'action' => 'login'));
        }`

Comment: It changes just for that model... How can I set the database for the whole application ? I tried $this->MyModel->setDataSource('teste'); But this changes just to that Model...